# How to get submitted files count from each input file

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have two input files on the client side and I need to specify the count of files submitted by each input file. I am able to get the total files count but I need to get how many files each input file submits

HTML:

```
   <input  type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"   multiple="multiple" />
   <input  type="file" id="myFile2" name="myFile2"   multiple="multiple" />
```

and I handle the upload process by ASP.NET Web Form button control
as follows:

```
protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Bytes", typeof(byte[]));
    dt.Columns.Add("ImgNames", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ImgType", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Member", typeof(int));

   // int firstFilesCount = Request.Files["myFile"].count; unable to do this 
   // int secondFilesCount = Request.Files["myFile2"].count; unable to do this so i need to 
   //get the count of files submitted by each input file
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Request.Files[i] != null && Request.Files[i].ContentLength > 0)
        {

            string fType = Request.Files[i].ContentType.Split('/')[1];
            string fName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);
            byte[] bytes = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[i].InputStream).ReadBytes(Request.Files[i].ContentLength);
            dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(hfAppID.Value), bytes, fName,
                fType, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["memberId"]));
        }
    }
    string outputStr = UpdateAttach()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to determine which file comes from which input by using the below code

```
var v = Request.Files.Keys;
```

This will return the ids of input files I used in my page to submit. So I am able to iterate through each input file by using `foreach` loop like below

```
foreach (string key in Request.Files)
{
    //processing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `Request.Files` might be a list of all the files regardless of what input they came from. If you use an `asp:FileUpload` control instead of a plain input, you can then access each input on the server side and should be able to use `myFile.PostedFiles.Count` and `myFile2.PostedFiles.Count` to get the number of files in each one.

Comment: yes i think so , but the issue is that the images is being resized after selection , so i gather them using hidden fields after resizing from div not from form submit body , like the way i put above,do you think  that the  array of posted files contains the images after resize or before ?i resize every image and  append it to a div , so i really dont know if its submitted resized or not,thats why , coz i have images to be resized and pdf's that i cant resize

Comment: You've lost me now, I'm not following your description of what you're doing to resize them. But to go back to the core question in your post: to get the # of files on each input to use on the server side, that input needs to be runat=server so the server can see it, or you need to get that number on the front end with javascript or something, and save it to some field that the server can see on postback. If you have a different question about how to do what you're trying to do in a broader sense, you might want to make a separate post, or update this one with a more thorough code example.

Comment: oh no problem i find the answer and posted it thanks so much